# cannot find postfix/mailx email in maildir, why not?

Tags: centos, postfix, smtp, email

In a `CentOS 7` development machine, I have configured postfix to allow emails to be traded between `localhost` addresses.  `Mailx` is also installed.  I am able to send email, and the log files indicate that the mail has been delivered.  However, I am not able to find the emails to view in the terminal.  **What am I doing wrong?  How can I view these newly sent emails in the terminal?**

I am able to send email by typing `mailx root@localhost` in the terminal and then following the prompts to add subject and body, then `Ctrl-D` to get the command prompt.  Also, when I type `mail` or `mailx` when logged in as root, the terminal responds with a list of a few old emails that were stored before `postfix` was changed to store emails in `/Maildir`, but there are no new emails to be found.  I can view those old emails when I type in `nano /var/spool/mail/root`, but of course the new emails are not stored in `/var/spool/mail/root`.

There is no `/var/log/mail`.  However, `nano /var/log/maillog` contains:

```
Jan  5 12:09:40 localhost postfix/postfix-script[6162]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jan  5 12:09:40 localhost postfix/master[6164]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Jan  5 12:46:00 localhost postfix/postfix-script[3036]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jan  5 12:46:00 localhost postfix/master[3047]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Jan  5 13:12:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[4642]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  5 13:12:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[4642]: DB1249A618: client=localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  5 13:12:02 localhost postfix/cleanup[4645]: DB1249A618: message-id=<1738078707.0.1420492322780.JavaMail.username@localhost.localdomain>
Jan  5 13:12:02 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: DB1249A618: from=<username@localhost.localdomain>, size=632, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 13:12:02 localhost postfix/smtpd[4642]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  5 13:12:02 localhost postfix/local[4646]: DB1249A618: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.06/0.02/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan  5 13:12:02 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: DB1249A618: removed
Jan  5 14:29:20 localhost postfix/pickup[5207]: 7F4439A616: uid=1000 from=<username>
Jan  5 14:29:20 localhost postfix/cleanup[5266]: 7F4439A616: message-id=<20150105222920.7F4439A616@localhost.localdomain>
Jan  5 14:29:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: 7F4439A616: from=<username@localhost.localdomain>, size=334, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 14:29:20 localhost postfix/local[5271]: 7F4439A616: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.1/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan  5 14:29:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: 7F4439A616: removed
Jan  5 14:57:10 localhost postfix/pickup[5207]: A21B49A618: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan  5 14:57:10 localhost postfix/cleanup[5529]: A21B49A618: message-id=<20150105225710.A21B49A618@localhost.localdomain>
Jan  5 14:57:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: A21B49A618: from=<root@localhost.localdomain>, size=534, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 14:57:10 localhost postfix/local[5531]: A21B49A618: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.38, delays=0.34/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan  5 14:57:10 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: A21B49A618: removed
Jan  5 15:47:38 localhost postfix/pickup[5207]: F312D9A618: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan  5 15:47:39 localhost postfix/cleanup[5975]: F312D9A618: message-id=<20150105234738.F312D9A618@localhost.localdomain>
Jan  5 15:47:39 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: F312D9A618: from=<root@localhost.localdomain>, size=458, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 15:47:39 localhost postfix/local[5977]: F312D9A618: to=<username@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<username@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.12, delays=0.09/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan  5 15:47:39 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: F312D9A618: removed
Jan  5 15:48:20 localhost postfix/pickup[5207]: A826C9A618: uid=1000 from=<username>
Jan  5 15:48:20 localhost postfix/cleanup[5975]: A826C9A618: message-id=<20150105234820.A826C9A618@localhost.localdomain>
Jan  5 15:48:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: A826C9A618: from=<username@localhost.localdomain>, size=461, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 15:48:20 localhost postfix/local[5977]: A826C9A618: to=<username@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<username@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.08/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan  5 15:48:20 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: A826C9A618: removed
Jan  5 15:48:29 localhost postfix/pickup[5207]: 54AA19A618: uid=1000 from=<username>
Jan  5 15:48:29 localhost postfix/cleanup[5975]: 54AA19A618: message-id=<20150105234829.54AA19A618@localhost.localdomain>
Jan  5 15:48:29 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: 54AA19A618: from=<username@localhost.localdomain>, size=461, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 15:48:29 localhost postfix/local[5977]: 54AA19A618: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.11, delays=0.09/0/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan  5 15:48:29 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: 54AA19A618: removed
Jan  5 15:52:03 localhost postfix/pickup[5207]: C756E9A618: uid=0 from=<root>
Jan  5 15:52:03 localhost postfix/cleanup[6074]: C756E9A618: message-id=<20150105235203.C756E9A618@localhost.localdomain>
Jan  5 15:52:03 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: C756E9A618: from=<root@localhost.localdomain>, size=491, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  5 15:52:03 localhost postfix/local[6076]: C756E9A618: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.09/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Jan  5 15:52:03 localhost postfix/qmgr[3058]: C756E9A618: removed
Jan  5 16:02:36 localhost postfix/smtpd[6213]: connect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
Jan  5 16:04:26 localhost postfix/smtpd[6213]: disconnect from localhost.localdomain[127.0.0.1]
```

**The logs say `delivered to maildir`.  Am I using the wrong syntax to access `maildir` contents?**

Also, `main.cf` is as follows (note it needs to allow localhost accounts to email each other):

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myorigin = localhost
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
relayhost = 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = 
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
    ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**EDIT:**

As per `masegaloeh`'s advice, I typed `nano ~/.mailrc` and added the following before saving:

```
set MAIL=/home/root/Maildir
set folder=mail
```

Next, I typed `mailx`, but the terminal responded with `No mail for root`.  So I created a new email with the following:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mailx
No mail for root
[root@localhost ~]# mailx root@localhost
Subject: another 905pm test.
gonna try again now.
EOT
[root@localhost ~]# mailx
No mail for root
```

**As you can see, there is no way to read the email I just sent.  What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default mailx will search read mbox file `/var/spool/mail/$username`. You can view it with below command (*credit to [beginlinux.com website](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/mail-server/1043-postfix-mailbox-changes)*)

```
$ set | grep -i mail
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/myuser
MAILCHECK=60
```

When you change parameter `home_mailbox` in postfix, you need to adjust the mailx configuration so it will search mail in new location. With `home_mailbox = Maildir/`, postfix will store the email in Maildir directory **relative with user home directory**.

Snippet from postfix [man postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox)

> **home_mailbox (default: empty)**
>
> ***Optional pathname of a mailbox file relative to a local(8) user's home directory.***
>
> Specify a pathname ending in "/" for qmail-style delivery.

So your email will stored in `$HOME/Maildir/`, with $HOME is your home directory. For root, his home directory is `/root/`; for other user, his home directory typically in `/home/otheruser/`. See [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524) explanation in [unix.SE: Root /home Directory vs ~ (tilde)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165774/66862).

In your case, you need to edit `~/.mailrc` and add these two lines

```
set MAIL=/root/Maildir
set folder=mail
```

References -> [Fedora Forum: ~/.mailrc changes](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=287377)

Comment: See edited answer (again). Comment wasn't proper place to [hold this piece of information](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Your answer works for the one `root` user, but not for other users.  I posted another question about configuring this for multiple users.  Are you willing to help me with this?  Here is the link:  http://serverfault.com/questions/656726/configuring-mailrc-for-multiple-maildir-users

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue all email sent to root@mydomain.co.uk were nto being saved to roots mailbox

i commented this line out in mail.cf
home_mailbox = Maildir/

then i had to set the owner of var/spool/mail/root to "root"

If you have other users than maybe you have to create a file in var/spool/mail/ folder with their username and also set the files owner to the same username?