# configuring .mailrc for multiple Maildir users

Tags: centos, postfix, email-server, email

In a CentOS 7 server with postfix and mailx, my `~/.mailrc` file contains:

```
set MAIL=/root/Maildir
set folder=mail
```

This enables mail from the `root` user's `Maildir` to be reviewed when the `root` user types in `mailx` at the `terminal`.  However, the above configuration does not allow any of the other users on the `CentOS 7` machine to be able to see their `Maildir` mail when they type `mailx` in the `terminal` when logged into their accounts.

How can I set global configuration of server to allow each of the other users to also see their `Maildir` email when they log into their accounts in the `terminal` and type `mailx`?  Do I create a separate `.mailrc` for each user?  If so, where do I put it?  And what do I add to `.mailrc`?

The seed for this came from [masegaloeh](https://serverfault.com/questions/656514/cannot-find-postfix-mailx-email-in-maildir-why-not/656528#656528).

Answer (score 0):

A common solution is to use an existing file or a new one called `mail.sh` in `/etc/profile.d/`:

```
MAIL=~/Maildir
```

At login, the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/` are executed by the user's shell and thus `MAIL` is set correctly for all users.

Comment: As root, I tried `nano /etc/profile.d/mail.sh`, the put `MAIL=~/Maildir` in that file and saved it.  Then I stopped and started `postfix`.  I then logged in as `username` and typed `mailx`, but it showed no emails for `username`.  So I tried `mailx username@localhost` and sent a new email to `username`.  Then I typed in `mailx` again, but it still showed no emails for `username`.  Do I need to delete `.mailrc` to make your solution work?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `echo $MAIL` give? This has nothing to do with postfix, just an issue of setting variables for the shell. `source /etc/profile.d/mail.sh` loads the file explicitly, maybe this show permission errors or so?

Comment: `echo $MAIL` gives `/var/spool/mail/username`

Comment: `nano /var/spool/mail/user` gives an empty file as well.

Comment: And this after loading the file directly using `source`? Very weird. You can also try putting it in `/etc/profile` to see if that works.

Comment: The shell login variables don't get expanded when performing mail lookup with `mail -u USERNAME`, since you're not loging in as that user into a terminal session, e.g.